# Rooftop Bars in Jakarta

Tags: indonesia, jakarta

Jakarta has many tourist attraction. Mountain, Beach, History and so many place here.

But I'm trying to find rooftop bars and lounge but until now is to difficult. Anyone can help me ?

For now I just found 5 recommendation:
http://www.citimhotel.com/blog/2016/10/16/5-rooftop-bars-dan-lounge-di-jakarta/

Comment: What exactly is your question? You have found five already! Voting to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: @mts: well, it's fairly difficult to say that what he is asking is unclear, as it's perfectly stated in the the question: more rooftop bars than the five he has already found. Problem here is OP is asking for a list and for personal suggestions, so this is vtc as too broad asking for opinion.